# Статичный сайт в Docker

Tags: nginx, docker, site

Сделал статичный сайт, визитку. Есть сервер, где могу разместить сайт, но там крутится Docker. Посетителей ожидается примерно 2 в пол года, так что нагрузки сильной не будет.
Проблема в том, что весь сайт (страница, таблицы стилей, изображения) лежат у меня на пк, а Docker на удаленном сервере. Пытался создать образ и контейнер по гайдам из интернета с использовагнием nginx, но там подразумевается, что сайт уже лежит на сервере. Помогите, подскажите пожалуйста, как можно решить эту задачку? На сервере есть Portrainer, пытался через него создать образ, он создается и монтируется как контейнер, nginx выдает свою тестовую страницу, но вот мой сайт показывать не хочет.

Comment: Так. То есть вы пытаетесь заставить работать сайт на СЕРВЕРЕ, если все файлы на вашем ЛОКАЛЬНОМ ПК? Или может я что-то не так понял? Может такое и практикуется, но как правило сайт заливается на сервер, на котором он будет функционировать. И зачем вам докер, если у вас статичный сайт-визитка? Почему нельзя просто создать на сервере виртуальный хост апача? Разворачивать для такого сайта докер-контейнер как-то слишком, на мой взгляд

Comment: Я и хочу уточнить как можно перенести файлы с локального пк в контейнер на сервере. Если он избыточен, можно только апач развернуть на сервере и всё?

Comment: Docker - это скорее про конфигурацию, а не про сами файлы. Какую задачу решаете? У Вас есть только файлы без Dockerfile? Тогда смысла в докере у вас никакого. Просто кидайте файлы в git, выкачивайте на сервере и запускайте через apache/nginx. И разберитесь в смысле докера, он нужен для создания идентичной среды выполнения что на локалке, что на продовой машине. Не для собирания статики в контейнеры.